# Skewed data: Is trimming the means necessary when using bootstrapping to compare means?

Tags: bootstrap, normality-assumption, skewness, robust, trimmed-mean

I want to compare four different groups on one dependent variable. Normally I'd do a one-way independent ANOVA, except that this time the normality assumption isn't met at all (see the below histograms of scores). The dependent variable is 'Total number of ECTS obtained', and most participants have a score of 60. I'd like to test whether there are significant between-group differences.

From Andy Field's 'Discovering statistics using R' I have identified two potential tests: the Kruskal-Wallis test, and Wilcox's (2005) robust ANOVA. I can run the KW test without problem. My question concerns the robust ANOVA. Field explains that there generally are two approaches for dealing with 'broken assumptions': working with trimmed means, and/or bootstrapping.

With Wilcox (2005)'s `t1waybt()` function (to be found [here](https://dornsife.usc.edu/labs/rwilcox/software/)), you can implement both approaches. My issue is that if I apply this function to my data WITH trimming the means (for example 10% or 20%), my results come out non-significant. If I apply bootstrapping WITHOUT trimming means, my results come out significant.

Of course, I don't want to select my approach based on posterior knowledge of the results. So what would be, from a conceptual point, the best way to deal with my skewed data? Should I trim the means, and why (not)?

[image: Histograms of the dependent variable per group]